# React throwing error related to Babel while trying to deploy in gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, runtime-error, babeljs, github-pages

I recently created a react app that I want to deploy in GitHub using gh-pages.
1. Installed gh-pages
2. Went to package.json and mentioned the homepage, predeploy and deploy commands.
3. Created a git repository and added remote origin.

When trying to run "npm run deploy", I am getting an error related to Babel.

```
Error: [BABEL] E:\Projects\project_eight\node_modules\axios\index.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "E:\\Projects\\project_eight\\node_modules\\babel-preset-react-app\\dependencies.js$0")
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

My Babel numeric separator plugin in package-lock.json is

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": {
      "version": "7.8.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator/-/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator-7.8.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-jWioO1s6R/R+wEHizfaScNsAx+xKgwTLNXSh7tTC4Usj3ItsPEhYkEpU4h+lpnBwq7NBVOJXfO6cRFYcX69JUQ==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/helper-plugin-utils": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-numeric-separator": "^7.8.3"
      }
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a current problem on CRA

I've found the solution in this thread on GH, it worked just fine using yarn 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8680#issuecomment-601896916